# Latest release of sonar maven plugin is broken

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

It looks like they released latest version of sonar maven plugin which is under org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.8.0.2131/
However it has a dependency below that is missing in the public maven repos :-

org.sonarsource.scanner.api:sonar-scanner-api:jar:2.16.0.226

The latest version i could find for this dependency is 2.15.0.2182 available in public repos

This is causing most of our build failures now where we use sonar goal in maven. I know we can fix this by specifying the version something like below :-

mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar

However, that would require us to make changes in a number of places.
Is anyone in the community aware of this and if so do we know if they are going to fix the latest version of sonar maven plugin and make all its dependencies available?

Comment: Can you explain where you found `org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.8.0.2131` this version? On Central there is only a version 3.7.0.1746... ?

Comment: In jenkins the mvn command just uses sonar:sonar so it always tries to pick up latest version available. This 3.8.0.2131 was released just this morning or may be yesterday and so it go cached in our artifactory and now builds are referring to this latest version and failing to find its dependency as that never existed.

Comment: If you build piks up the most recent version you have not defined the version in your build... which you should do... to make your build reliable.. And the release is being tagged 6 hours ago on GitHub ... so synch can take a while in Central....

Comment: Ah ok so this latest 3.8.0.2131 has indeed been released and we should just wait for few more hours. Could you please provide me the GitHub link where i can find it?

Comment: ok i found it at
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-maven/releases/tag/3.8.0.2131

Answer (score 2):

For the moment you can specify in your Jenkins job the version of the plugin :

```
mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar
```

[SonarSCanner for Maven](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/)

Comment: The versions are now updated in the public repos. 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.8.0.2131/
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.16.0.226/